# How to upload bufferedimage to Google Cloud Storage?

Tags: spring-boot, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

I want to use Google Cloud Storage to store the static picture uploaded. Most samples upload a txt or part file.

I checked a lot of documents from Google but still don't know how to upload
a bufferedimage or image.

The img I want to upload is all edit locally. So although they come as multipart but finally they become bufferedimage.

The result for the following code is a nullpointer:

```
@PostMapping("/productImages")
public Object add(@RequestParam("pid") int pid, @RequestParam("type") String type, MultipartFile image, HttpServletRequest request) throws Exception {
    String fileName = image.getOriginalFilename();
    String mimeType = request.getServletContext().getMimeType(fileName);
    if (!mimeType.startsWith("image/")) {
       return 0;
    }
    ProductImage bean = new ProductImage();
    Product product = productService.get(pid);
    bean.setProduct(product);
    bean.setType(type);
    String folder = "/img/";
    if(type_single.equals(bean.getType())){
        folder +="productSingle/";
    }
    else{
        folder +="productDetail/";
    }
//        BufferedImage bufferedImage = convertToImage(image);
    File  imageFolder= new File(request.getServletContext().getRealPath(folder));
    System.out.println(request.getServletContext().getRealPath(folder));
    File file = new File(imageFolder,bean.getId()+".jpg");
    String descName = folder+bean.getId()+".jpg";
//        if(!file.getParentFile().exists())
//            file.getParentFile().mkdirs();
    try {
//            image.transferTo(file);
        BufferedImage img = ImageUtil.change2jpg(file);
        System.out.println(descName);
        System.out.println(image.getOriginalFilename());
        googleCloudStorage.uploadFile(img,descName);
        productImageService.add(bean);
//            ImageIO.write(img, "jpg", file);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

**GoogleCloudStorage class**:

```
public class GoogleCloudStorage {
private Storage storage;
private Bucket bucket;
String pathToConfig  = "/google_auth.json";
String projectId = "gogogo";
String bucketName = "gogog-image";
public GoogleCloudStorage() throws IOException {
    Credentials credentials = GoogleCredentials.fromStream(new FileInputStream(pathToConfig));
    storage = StorageOptions.newBuilder().setCredentials(credentials).setProjectId(projectId).build().getService();
    bucket = storage.get(bucketName);
}

public String uploadFile(BufferedImage bufferedImage, String fileName) throws IOException{
    System.out.println("123");

    ByteArrayOutputStream os = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    BlobInfo blobInfo = storage.create(BlobInfo.newBuilder(bucketName,fileName).setAcl(new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(Acl.of(User.ofAllUsers(), Role.READER)))).build(),bufferedImage.());
    return blobInfo.getMediaLink();
}
```

ImageUtil

```
public static BufferedImage change2jpg(File f) {
    try {
        Image i = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().createImage(f.getAbsolutePath());
        PixelGrabber pg = new PixelGrabber(i, 0, 0, -1, -1, true);
        pg.grabPixels();
        int width = pg.getWidth(), height = pg.getHeight();
        final int[] RGB_MASKS = { 0xFF0000, 0xFF00, 0xFF };
        final ColorModel RGB_OPAQUE = new DirectColorModel(32, RGB_MASKS[0], RGB_MASKS[1], RGB_MASKS[2]);
        DataBuffer buffer = new DataBufferInt((int[]) pg.getPixels(), pg.getWidth() * pg.getHeight());
        WritableRaster raster = Raster.createPackedRaster(buffer, width, height, width, RGB_MASKS, null);
        BufferedImage img = new BufferedImage(RGB_OPAQUE, raster, false, null);
        return img;
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: What exactly are you trying to upload?  Some binary representation of what's in the BufferedImage?  A png?  A jpg?  Something else?

Comment: @DougStevenson the image uploaded should be in png or jpg or jpeg , and I use some method change the multipart to bufferedimge . I can do that locally.and this is what I want to upload

Comment: OK, what did you do to convert it locally, and what's the code you added for that?

Comment: At which line NPE gets thrown?

Comment: ＠Doug Stevenson sorry, I mean I can save img inside jar file.and change2jpg change file to bufferedimage

Comment: @Vusal googleCloudStorage.uploadFile(img,descName); and didn't print "123"

Comment: @Vusal sorry to ask you again, but i still cant make this work. can you give some advice?